# How to create reports with DevExpress Reporting tools with Entity Framework

Tags: silverlight, devexpress, report

When I create a report with Dev Express for SilverLight and I want to choose a datasource, I don't find anything. However, I have numerous entities, contexts, .. That should be acceptable data sources.

I followed the tutorials on DevExpress documentation site but they are using datasets which isn't what I need.

What should I do to bind my data ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check [XtraReportBase.DataSource Property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXtraReportBase_DataSourcetopic) to know that what datasource you can provide to report..

you can provide data as entities also, but little more effort require with EF.

[Entity Framework for Report Datasource](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q337973.aspx)
[Using ADO.NET Entity Data Model as DataSource for XtraReport](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q334458.aspx)

For your reference check these links: [search link](http://search.devexpress.com/default.aspx?q=report%20datasource&p=T4%7CP3%7C20&page=1)
[Bind a Report to Data without a Data Source at Design Time](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument5149/BindingSource)
[How to: Bind a Report to a List Object at Design Time and Provide Data at Runtime](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument7547)
[Report with Parameters filled on runtime in silverlight](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q262091.aspx)
[Silverlight Reporting](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q330536.aspx)